# Ajax call not getting executed, throws undefined error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, razor

I am writing a basic GET call using jquery AJAX in C# using MVC 4.
My code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
             $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/GetData",
            content: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (success) {
                var jsonData = success;
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

But I am getting following error:

[image]

Can someone please help me here. I have already spent a day with no luck yet.

Comment: The slim version of jQuery doesn't include the $.ajax api, use full version

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a ton @charlietfl